# SQL Query to match events that occur between a set of 30-second time segments

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a query where I want to get events that occur in between a set of times that are 30 seconds long.

Example:

If I use this query:

```
SELECT videotime FROM codes
    WHERE participant = 2 AND (retrospective ='y' AND forks > 0)
```

Output:

```
00:16:30.000
00:21:00.000
00:21:30.000
00:27:00.000
00:38:30.000
```

Then I want to get events from another table at 00:16:31, 00:16:32, but also 00:21:01, 00:27:29.999, etc.

What I've written so far only matches the first row (00:16:30) but I would like to be able to make it match more.

```
SELECT id, videotime FROM commands WHERE participant = 2 AND
videotime >= (SELECT videotime FROM codes
    WHERE participant = 2 AND (retrospective ='y' AND forks > 0) ) AND
videotime <= time((SELECT videotime FROM codes
    WHERE participant = 2 AND (retrospective ='y' AND forks > 0) ), '+30 seconds');
```

Incorrect output from above:

```
28          00:16:31.021
29          00:16:31.635
30          00:16:34.948
31          00:16:35.004
32          00:16:37.101
33          00:16:37.144
34          00:16:37.992
35          00:16:38.029
36          00:16:42.740
37          00:16:42.910
38          00:16:43.724
39          00:16:49.756
40          00:16:49.836
41          00:16:58.788
42          00:16:58.834
43          00:16:59.936
```

What do I need to do to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with sqlite whatsoever so my answer may very well be syntactically incorrect but hopefully the basic point will be clear:

```
SELECT id, videotime
FROM commands
WHERE participant = 2
      AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT time
        FROM (SELECT videotime 
              FROM codes
              WHERE participant = 2 
                    AND (retrospective ='y' AND forks > 0)) AS times
        WHERE commands.videotime - times.videotime >= 0
              AND commands.videotime - times.videotime <= 30
      )
```

(especially the syntax for the time differences in seconds is likely different from what I'm writing here but I hope you / someone can adjust it accordingly)

Comment: Wonderful! I had to change the date format for SQLite3 to ```strftime('%s', commands.videotime) - strftime('%s', times.videotime) <= 30``` for it to calculate seconds.